# IllegalArgumentException: "Missing provider" in bouncyCastle

Tags: java, linux, bouncycastle, jboss5.x

I am using jboss 5.1.0 and i am facing an unusual problem with bouncy castle jar.

I have 4 different machine with same configured os ,jdk, jboss servers and bouncy castle jar in `jboss/server/default/lib`.

But I am facing problem of `IllegalArgumentException:"missing provider"` and I found that it is occurring due to jar but i couldn't find out why it is working on my 2 systems but not in other 2 .

on windows it is working fine.

I am installing BouncyCastle dynamically by `Security.insertProviderAt(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);`.

Comment: is you problem resolved?